# How to keep origin in center of image in scale animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a situation similar to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddvn3p1h/3/), where I have a CSS3 animation that scales an element absolute-positioned in the centre of another element. However, when the animation takes place it is off-centre, as seen by the red squares relative to blue in the example. How do I centre it? I have tried a couple of configurations around the `transform-origin` property, but this isn't producing the correct results.

```css
@keyframes ripple_large {
 0% {transform:scale(1); }
 75% {transform:scale(3); opacity:0.4;}
 100% {transform:scale(4); opacity:0;}
}

.container {
  position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
  transform-origin:center;
}

.one {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pixiebob-cat.jpg' class='cat'>
  <div class='center-point'>
  </div>
  <div class='to-animate one'></div>
  <div class='to-animate two'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue is that you are overriding the `translate` transformation.

When you specify a new transformation (the one inside the animation) it **override** the first one. In your case you **are removing the translation** that is fixing the **center** alignment.

You need to add them to the same `transform` property and pay attention to the order because it's important ([Why does order of transforms matter? rotate/scale doesn't give the same result as scale/rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53671968/8620333))

```css
@keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(3);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
}

.one {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  -webkit-animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pixiebob-cat.jpg' class='cat'>
  <div class='center-point'>
  </div>
  <div class='to-animate one'></div>
  <div class='to-animate two'></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

As commented, it's better to center your element using another method than translation to avoid changing the animation since this can be used with other elements.

Example:

```css
@keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) ;
  }
  75% {
    transform:scale(3) ;
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(4) ;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
  transform-origin:center;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
}

.one {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img src='http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Pixiebob-cat.jpg' class='cat'>
  <div class='center-point'>
  </div>
  <div class='to-animate one'></div>
  <div class='to-animate two'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Either that or use (*in this specific case*) `margin` to center the element, since the `width`/`height` are fixed. In case they want to keep the `keyframes` agnostic to the element that it is applied.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes sure ;) i focused on the way they override and added them to animation to show it. But i agree that it's better to fix alignement in other way :)

Comment: Not sure if my suggestion is really better, i just wanted to mention an alternative solution.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli i think in general it's better as we can for example consider the case where we use some external library that add animation on transform and in this case we cannot change the animation and it's better to change CSS of our element.

Answer (score 1):

By using `transform: scale(1);` onto an already defined *transform* property like `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` you will lose (override) the *translate* with *scale*-only.

Either

- repeat the desired like `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);` or rather:
- use the CSS3 `scale:` and `translate:` properties on their own:

```css
@keyframes ripple_large {
  0% {
    scale: 1;  /* CHANGED THIS */
  }
  75% {
    scale: 3;  /* CHANGED THIS */
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    scale: 4;  /* CHANGED THIS */
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10vmax;
}

.cat {
  height: 20vmax;
}

.center-point {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%; /* CHANGED THIS */
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: blue;
}

.to-animate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  translate: -50% -50%; /* CHANGED THIS */
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5vmax;
  width: 5vmax;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.one {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 0s infinite;
}

.two {
  animation: ripple_large 2s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBCIk.jpg" class="cat">
  <div class="center-point">
  </div>
  <div class="to-animate one"></div>
  <div class="to-animate two"></div>
</div>
```