# How to center arrow created with border and transform?

Tags: css

How to centre this type of arrows? I tried with transform but it didn't work. Ex:

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform: rotate(135deg) translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translate then rotate, [order is important](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672795/8620333)

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(black,black) center/10px 10px no-repeat,
   pink;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

And if you want to consider only the arrow, adjust  the left position:

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(black,black) center/10px 10px no-repeat,
   pink;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% + 15px);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Or the translation:

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(black,black) center/10px 10px no-repeat,
   pink;
  position: relative;
}

.test::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform: translate(-25%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Here is the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zvLexnay/) I was working on.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the CSS for `arrow::before` by making `arrow` by using the CSS in the code snippet.

```css
.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*positiom: relative;*/
}

.test::before {
    content: '';
  /*position: absolute;*/
   /*top: 50%;*/
   /*left: 50%;
  /*display: inline-block; */
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform: rotate(135deg) translate(-20%, -20%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Aside from saving you a few lines of code you don't have to mess around with absolute positioning in case you want to make adjustments in the future.